# function()() don't understand the extra parentheses.How does it get executed?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

```
    function times(x){
      return function(y){
        return function(z){
          return  x*y*z;
        }
      };
    }
```

A bit confused how does this exactly work? How does that function know that the next parentheses is the argument for the inside return function?

```
console.log(times(2)(5)(2))  // 20
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
times(2)
```

Executes the function `times`.  But look at what that function returns:

```
function times(x){
  return function(y){
    //...
  }
}
```

It returns a function.  So *that* function, as the return value of `times(2)`, can itself be executed:

```
times(2)(5)
```

That function *also* returns a function, which itself is also executed:

```
times(2)(5)(2)
```

Basically, in JavaScript a function is an object like any other.  It can be passed as an argument, returned, set to a variable, or just executed inline without ever needing to be named or otherwise referenced.

So this:

```
times(2)(5)
```

Is *roughly* equivalent to this:

```
var func = times(2);
func(5);
```

But without the need for a variable to store that initial return value, it just executes it in-line as it's returned.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `times(2)(5)(2)`, you are basically doing `((times(2))(5))(2)`, which means `times(2)` will be evaluated, which will return a function, then that function will be evaluated with `(5)` and so on.

A better example:

```
function a(){
    return {b: 'c'}
}

a().b //c
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the first function returns another function which in turn returns another function.

It is same as calling all the three functions one after the other.

```
var func1 = times(2);
var func2 = func1(3);
var func3 = func2(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

One after another:

```
function times(x){
  return function first(y){
    return function second(z){
      return  x*y*z;
    }
  };
}

var progress=times(1);
```

Progress is now a pointer to first, as first was returned by times. X is bound to it ( have a look at Closures...)

```
progress=progress(2);
```

Progress is now second, as Second is returned by First.

```
progress=progress(3);//1*2*3
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept is called [currying](https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe).

So what it does is this :

```
var result1 = times(2); //==> returns a function
var result2 = result1(5); //==> returns a function
var result3 = result2(5); //==> returns a product
```

Comment: The concept of returning a function from within a function is not currying, that is the concept of closures. Yes you *can* curry in this way, but true currying checks the number of arguments passed and determines the function (if any) to return. True currying in this example would return a product if you said `times(2,5,5)`

Comment: why the f this has been downvoted when the duplicate marking is based on what I mentioned here

Comment: I did not downvote this, but it looks like someone came by and downvoted all the answers. You are correct in that the question marked as a duplicate is about currying, however, it has been incorrectly marked, as I mentioned in my comment. However, they likely downvoted because answering duplicate questions is frowned upon.

Comment: @mhodges I apologize upfront if i sounded accusing , i did not mean to ask you  "why the downvote", in general I had asked why. And I do see your point in saying why this isnt exactly currying but could be called as part of it - All dogs are animals but not all animals are dogs analogy